# Main Imac Screen black external ok

Tags: imac

on iMac, the external display works but internal is backlit but black

When I change resolution the main screen gets lines on it then goes back to black

Comment: Did anything unusual precede this (gradual degradation, just woke up one day this way, software installs or updates, etc.)?

Comment: There was a prior occurrence, I took it apart checked all the connectors and put it back with a new hard drive and SL.  It worked fine after numerous cold boots.  Put Lion upgrade on and display went dark, lion installed fine since it was a virgin SL to start with

Comment: When it starts from cold with second monitor plugged in the screen gets a very large light flare for a second before going dark just prior to the second screen coming up perfectly

Comment: It sounds like you didn't discover the cause of the original occurence, but that checking the display connector may have fixed something? Is there any reason to suspect connector issues again (f/ex, if you'd been moving the machine alot)?  Otherwise, my next thought is to backup, reinstall SL and see if normal behavior returns (suggesting drivers in Lion) or not (suggesting hardware).  Bit of PITA, but maybe less so than opening the box again.

Comment: Trying to get the hardware diagnostics for this model now to see if its the lcd thats gone, much better than opening up again thanks